# What does it mean? "my sister being who she was (harry potter)"

Tags: meaning

In the first movie of Harry Potter, after Hagrid breaks the door and comes in, Aunt Petunia says about Lily:

> my sister being who she was

I wonder what does it mean?

Comment: She was living up to her standards of behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Being who she was" simply means that in Petunia's mind Lily was behaving the exactly way Petunia would expect her to behave, that is, she was "acting in character".

In this particular case it also conveys some disapproval, but the phrase could equally well imply approval, admiration, scorn, or any other attitude: "Joe Hero, being who he was, of course ran into the burning building to save [insert name of heroine here]."

"Mickey, being who he was, could not restrain himself from responding to a question on english.stackexchange, even though he had more important things to do at the moment".

Answer (score 0):

She was referring to how she thought Lily was a "freak".

Comment: But the same phrasing could be used refer to someone who was violent or withdrawn or the "life of the party".

Comment: Hello, Daniel. Correct, but questions about specific interpretations of pieces of writing etc, where there may quite be a different interpretation (equally valid) in another novel, are off-topic on ELU and should be close-voted. They belong on Literature.SE.

Comment: Right, thanks for clarifying, as you could tell I am new to this, but cheers for the heads up.